# Why do we need list_for_each_safe() in for deleting nodes in kernel linked list?

Tags: c, foreach, linux-kernel, linked-list, kernel

I'm learning how to use the kernel linked-list API from [list.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/list.h).

I learned that I need to use `list_for_each_safe()` when deleting nodes off with `list_del()` instead of using `list_for_each()`.

Code for `list_for_each_safe()`:

```
#define list_for_each_safe(pos, n, head) \
    for (pos = (head)->next, n = pos->next; pos != (head); \
        pos = n, n = pos->next)
```

Code for `list_for_each()`:

```
    for (pos = (head)->next; pos != (head); pos = pos->next)
```

I notice they both are very similar except that the `_safe` version takes an extra argument to be used as 'temporary storage' (stated here, [list.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/list.h)).

I understand when to apply the function correcly, `_safe` version for deleting, normal version for accessing, but I'm curious how the extra argument made it 'safe'?

Consider the following, where I'm deleting every node in a linked list using `list_for_each_safe()`:

```
struct kool_list{
    int to;
    struct list_head list;
    int from;
    };

struct kool_list *tmp;
struct list_head *pos, *q;
struct kool_list mylist;

list_for_each_safe(pos, q, &mylist.list){
         tmp= list_entry(pos, struct kool_list, list);
         printf("freeing item to= %d from= %d\n", tmp->to, tmp->from);
         list_del(pos);
         free(tmp);
    }
```

How does giving `q` help in deleting?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I got it, never thought it is this straight forward, thanks !

Comment: q should have been named in a better way.. something like pos_next.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That is necessary because `list_del` internally modifies the value of `pos` fields. In your example the loop body even frees the memory occupied by `pos`. Suppose that you would use unsafe version of the loop:

```
for (pos = (head)->next; pos != (head); pos = pos->next)
```

After executing the loop body `pos` pointer becomes invalid breaking the increment expression: `pos = pos->next`.

As opposite, the safe foreach pre-saves the value of `pos->next` in a temporary variable and then refers to the latter instead of dereferencing `pos`:

```
for (pos = (head)->next, n = pos->next; pos != (head); \
    pos = n, n = pos->next)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
pos = start;
del(pos);
pos = pos->next;
```

as opposed to

```
pos = start;
n = pos->next;
del(pos);
pos = n;
```

if del() is free() and memset(), pos->next is undefined