# Clear Linux Kernel Linked List

Tags: c++, c, linux, list

I'm trying to modify some code that uses the C linked list used in the linux kernel, like [this one](http://www.kraxel.org/cgit/fbida/tree/list.h) used in fbida.  But I need to actually clear the list and start from scratch and I am unsure of the safest way to do that. Nor can I find a example online.

Any ideas on how to safely clear the list and free all the memory?

Comment: Why is the question tagged C++? You won't find that language used in the Linux kernel as long as [this guy](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/57918) has any say in the matter.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I think it's a userland program using an implementation similar to the lists used in the Linux kernel.

Comment: @AdamHaile Why do this when you have the might of `std::list` ?

Comment: I'm modifying code that I did not write initially. The current implementation uses the kernel linked list so I was trying to use the same because otherwise I would have to rewrite much of it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207850/why-do-we-need-list-for-each-safe-in-for-deleting-nodes-in-kernel-linked-list for a correct answer to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I found the answer (figures...)
Would something like the following work?

```
void delete_all(struct list_head *head)
{
    struct list_head *iter;
    struct foo *objPtr;

  redo:
    __list_for_each(iter, head) {
        objPtr = list_entry(iter, struct foo, list_member);
        list_del(&objPtr->list_member);
        free(objPtr);
        goto redo;
    }
}
```

Comment: well, more specifically what's the difference between the above and your implementation, @cnicutar ?

Comment: You should call free() only if you use malloc, calloc, realloc (or another compatible allocation routine).  MS has many others that are incompat.  And if you move to c++, you might use "new" which requires a "delete" to free.

Answer (score 0):

"safest way"... "to free memory"...  The referenced code does no allocation, it is entirely upto the caller/implementer to allocate the memory.  Therefore, the caller/implementer must free the allocated memory.

Per "cnicutar", it is simply a job of iterating through the list, calling the list_del(), function on each item found, then free-ing or deleting the object depending upon how it was allocated.