# Understanding list_del_rcu() and list_for_each_entry() working

Tags: list, multithreading, linked-list, linux-kernel

I am learning RCU link-list kernel APIs. My program is having 2 writers and 1 readers, after every second both writers will come and either add new node or *delete the entire list* if number of nodes are divisible by 5 completely. However despite having spin lock protection, I am getting NOPTI, I believe it is a case of accessing deleted node again. But how? I am not releasing the lock before `list_del_rcu()` call.

```c
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/spinlock.h>
#include <linux/rcupdate.h>
#include <linux/kthread.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>

#define RD_THREAD               1
#define WR_THREAD               2
#define THREAD_NAME             16

static DEFINE_SPINLOCK(spl);
static struct task_struct       *task_read[RD_THREAD], *task_write[WR_THREAD];
typedef struct {
        struct list_head        node;
        int                     value;
} node_t;

static LIST_HEAD(head);
static atomic_t         total;

static int read_func(void *arg)
{
        node_t                  *curNode;

        while (!kthread_should_stop()) {
                ssleep(10);
                rcu_read_lock();
                list_for_each_entry_rcu(curNode, &head, node) {
                        printk(KERN_CONT "-> %d ", curNode->value);
                }
                printk(KERN_INFO "");
                rcu_read_unlock();
        }
        return 0;
}

static int write_func(void *arg)
{
        int                     counter = 0;
        node_t                  *newNode, *oldNode, *temp;
        int                     choice = 0;

        while (!kthread_should_stop()) {
                ssleep(1);
                switch (choice) {

                        case 0:
                                newNode = kmalloc(sizeof (*newNode), GFP_KERNEL);
                                if (!newNode) {
                                        printk(KERN_ERR "No memory left.\n");
                                        break;
                                }
                                newNode->value = counter++;
                                spin_lock(&spl);
                                list_add_rcu(&newNode->node, &head);
                                atomic_inc(&total);
                                spin_unlock(&spl);
                                break;

                        case 1:
                                if (counter % 5)
                                {
                                        break;
                                }
                                spin_lock(&spl);
                                list_for_each_entry_safe(oldNode, temp, &head, node) {

                                        /*
                                         * Print node content.
                                         */

                                        printk(KERN_INFO "Add %p %d %s %d\n",
                                               (void *)oldNode, oldNode->value,
                                               current->comm, atomic_read(&total));

                                        list_del_rcu(&oldNode->node);
                                        atomic_dec(&total);
                                        spin_unlock(&spl);

                                        synchronize_rcu();

                                        kfree(oldNode);
                                        spin_lock(&spl);

                                }
                                spin_unlock(&spl);
                                break;
                        default:
                                choice = -1;
                                break;
                }
                choice++;
        }

        spin_lock(&spl);
        list_for_each_entry_safe(oldNode, temp, &head, node) {
                list_del_rcu(&oldNode->node);
                spin_unlock(&spl);
                synchronize_rcu();
                kfree(oldNode);
                spin_lock(&spl);
        }
        spin_unlock(&spl);
        return 0;
}

static void end(void)
{
        int                     rc;
        unsigned int            counter;

        for (counter = 0; counter < RD_THREAD; ++counter) {
                if (task_read[counter] && !IS_ERR(task_read[counter])) {
                        rc = kthread_stop(task_read[counter]);
                        printk(KERN_INFO "read_func_%u stopped with rc (%d)\n", counter, rc);
                }
        }
        for (counter = 0; counter < WR_THREAD; ++counter) {
                if (task_write[counter] && !IS_ERR(task_write[counter])) {
                        rc = kthread_stop(task_write[counter]);
                        printk(KERN_INFO "write_func_%u stopped with rc (%d)\n", counter, rc);
                }
        }
        printk(KERN_INFO "Module unloaded.\n");
        return;
}

static int __init start(void)
{
        unsigned int            counter;
        char                    thread_name[THREAD_NAME] = { 0 };

        for (counter = 0; counter < WR_THREAD; ++counter) {
                snprintf(thread_name, THREAD_NAME, "write_func_%d", counter);
                task_write[counter] = kthread_create(write_func, NULL, thread_name);
                if (IS_ERR(task_write[counter])) {
                        end();
                        printk(KERN_ERR "Failed to create %s (%ld)\n", thread_name, PTR_ERR(task_write[counter]));
                        return PTR_ERR(task_write[counter]);
                } else {
                        wake_up_process(task_write[counter]);
                }
        }
        for (counter = 0; counter < RD_THREAD; ++counter) {
                snprintf(thread_name, THREAD_NAME, "read_func_%d", counter);
                task_read[counter] = kthread_create(read_func, NULL, thread_name);
                if (IS_ERR(task_read[counter])) {
                        end();
                        printk(KERN_ERR "Failed to create %s (%ld)\n", thread_name, PTR_ERR(task_read[counter]));
                        return PTR_ERR(task_read[counter]);
                } else {
                        wake_up_process(task_read[counter]);
                }
        }
        printk(KERN_INFO "Module started.\n");
        return 0;
}

module_init(start);
module_exit(end);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("MP");
```

dmesg:

> [ 6124.396574] Module started. 
> [ 6134.590443] -> 2 -> 2 -> 1 -> 1 -> 0
> -> 0 
> [ 6134.590451] 
> [ 6138.750431] Add 00000000f8506a7d 4 write_func_1 10 
> [ 6138.750435] Add 0000000089a4bcde 4 write_func_0 9 
> [ 6138.756419]
> Add 0000000089a4bcde 4 write_func_1 8 
> [ 6138.756423] list_del
> corruption, ffff905962895a40->prev is LIST_POISON2 (dead000000000200)
>
> [ 6138.756464] ------------[ cut here ]------------ [ 6138.756464]
> kernel BUG at lib/list_debug.c:50! 
> [ 6138.756484] invalid opcode: 0000
> [#1] SMP NOPTI 
> [ 6138.756501] CPU: 3 PID: 19796 Comm: write_func_1
> Kdump: loaded Tainted: P           OE    --------- -  -
> 4.18.0-372.9.1.el8.x86_64 #1

Comment: "Understanding list_del() and list_for_each_entry() working" - They are not working together. For remove elements from a list during the iteration, use `list_for_each_entry_safe` instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207850/why-do-we-need-list-for-each-safe-in-for-deleting-nodes-in-kernel-linked-list.

Comment: Note also, that since you unlock the spinlock **inside** a foreach loop, the other thread may modify the list before you acquire the spinlock again. Even `list_for_each_entry_safe` is not prepared to such modifications. Your usage of `synchronize_rcu` is plain wrong: you are not using RCU read sections.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we need list\_for\_each\_safe() in for deleting nodes in kernel linked list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207850/why-do-we-need-list-for-each-safe-in-for-deleting-nodes-in-kernel-linked-list)

Comment: @Tsyvarev, actually I was trying to implement RCU 1 reader and 2 writer, but failed to implement that because list_del_rcu was giving me LIST_POISON2 error so switched back to normal list, synchronize_rcu() is dead code. Yes it is right that list_for_each_entry_safe() works fine for normal case. But in case of RCU it failed.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, Have edited the original post to accomodate RCU writer scenario too. and reader side spin_(un)lock() will be replaced with rcu_read_(un)lock() APIs and list_for_each_entry() will be replaced by list_for_each_entry_rcu(). So can consider my original problem is related to RCU not normal list. Sorry for that.

Comment: As I said above, unlocking a spinlock at every iteration makes your **writers** to be not thread-safe: One writer may modify a list while the other writer iterates over it. Instead of combination of `synchronize_rcu();` and `kfree(oldNode);` you could use `kfree_rcu` function; this function can perfectly be called with a locked spinlock.

Comment: "So can consider my original problem is related to RCU not normal list." - Please, update your question post to reflect **only** your actual problem. It will be a problem for which one could write an answer. Also, try to **simplify** your code, see [mcve].

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I was following this link https://lwn.net/Articles/262464/ Here in very last comment by Mr. PaulMcKenney, he describes multiple concurrent list (mutiple writers). "As I said above, unlocking a spinlock at every iteration makes your writers to be not thread-safe:" Can we say that code is wrong?

Comment: "Please, update your question post to reflect only your actual problem..."  Updated it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When iterate by `list_for_each_entry_safe()` over the list, which may be modified by other threads, **all iterations** should be protected by a **single critical section**.

But in the cycle

```c
list_for_each_entry_safe(oldNode, temp, &head, node)
{
    /*
     * Print node content.
     */
    printk(KERN_INFO "Add %p %d %s %d\n",
           (void *)oldNode, oldNode->value,
           current->comm, atomic_read(&total));

    list_del_rcu(&oldNode->node);
    atomic_dec(&total);
    spin_unlock(&spl); // <- release the spinlock

    synchronize_rcu();

    kfree(oldNode);
    spin_lock(&spl); // <- acquire the spinlock again, but the protection is already broken
}
```

you release the spin lock **between** the iterations.

The function `list_for_each_entry_safe()` uses a pointer to the next element as the iterator. So, if a concurrent writer removes that next element, the iterator becomes invalid.

It is possible to avoid releasing the spinlock at every iteration by using `kfree_rcu()` function instead of pair of
`synchronize_rcu()` and `kfree()`:

```c
list_for_each_entry_safe(oldNode, temp, &head, node)
{
    /*
     * Print node content.
     */
    printk(KERN_INFO "Add %p %d %s %d\n",
           (void *)oldNode, oldNode->value,
           current->comm, atomic_read(&total));

    list_del_rcu(&oldNode->node);
    atomic_dec(&total);
    // The element will be removed via kfree after a grace period.
    kfree_rcu(oldNode, rcu);
}
```

The above code implies that you add `rcu` field to your element's structure:

```c
typedef struct {
        struct list_head        node;
        int                     value;
        struct rcu_head         rcu;
} node_t;
```

Comment: I think, I misread this article, lwn.net/Articles/262464 (very last comment)

Author never said to iterate, he was just saying about find_an_element(), so there situation is allowing us to release the lock before synchronize_rcu(), but my program's behaviour is diffetent specially due to call to list_for_each_entry_safe().

Comment: Yes, the last comment in the article doesn't delete an element during the iteration: it deletes the element after the whole iteration has been performed (possibly, in `find_an_element` function).